# Job title and duties

Tags: title

My job is a central planner/analyst however my job has become a Transport Planning Manager.

I control software upgrades, I train staff, I've wrote processes, I often work out of hours, have been still working when I'm off sick (as no one else is that capable above basic duties) I help manage staff, host meetings, occasional presentations and am the figurepoint of a national Transport Planning department.

My boss is usually approachable, but he's seemed to have put his foot down on this and highlighted a noticeable dip in performance after my dad had died which did last a few months to be totally honest, even though days after the funeral I was working out of hours.

My company are normally very good, but they have a history of keeping wages low and Ive never questioned them before on this, but my circumstances have changed and I'm very much in poverty at present and am a full time single dad?!

Can anyone advise as I don't want to upset a good employment, but I can't keep living like this and I believe I'm being underpaid by at least 10k a year?

Comment: If you are underpaid and having serious problem financially, I can't call your current job **a good employment**. You may be a good employee for your company, but it's certainly not a good employment for you, and it's up to you to do something about it.

Answer (score 2):

**This isn't good employment.**  A good employer respects your time off, compensates you satisfactorily, and would encourage you to get help to deal with a performance dip after a death in the family through proper treatment.

If you're in the US and you qualify, consider using FMLA to get some psychiatric help.  Therapy can help you grieve effectively and address the workplace issues that are adding to your stress.  I cannot emphasize enough how important it is to learn healthy coping strategies.

Stop working when you're out sick.  You earn that time off and use it to get better.  If your position is unable to be covered when you're out sick due to lack of cross-training, that is your management's issue to resolve and not yours.  You can delegate tasks to others if it is within your purview or let your management know what you're expecting to happen while you're out, but never perform work off the clock.  The owners are profiting off of you putting yourself second.

Brush off that resume and update it, and start job hunting.  See if you can find a higher-paying job at a larger company.  Once you get an offer, you can negotiate with your current management to see if they're willing to keep you (though, I never really recommend sticking around at a company that runs as yours does).